# Возврат HTTP 200 OK вместо нормального ответа

Tags: php, http, curl

Паршу ссылку с помощью curl и simple html dom, в браузере перехожу по ссылке - все ок и все доступно, однако при работе скрипта c ссылками на, непосредственно, страницы самих изображений, возвращает вместо данных лишь:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Date: Wed, 25 Apr 2018 09:32:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=3600;
```

Как исправить это? Конкретно на данный ответ была использована ссылка -> [Тык](https://gelbooru.com/index.php?page=post&s=view&id=4187841)
 В браузере захожу без всяких там сессий и логин\паролей, как гость, и все показывает и открывает нормально.
Curl сконфигурирован следующим образом:

```
function getSslPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

При этом если парсить главную страницу галереи и прочее, то все нормально присылает.Ошибка возникает лишь при переходе по адресам изображений.
var_dump($result) выдает следующее:

```
string(0) ""
```

Comment: Этот код с переданной ему ссылкой, у меня отрабатывает нормально и в консоли и в браузере. Возможно не весь результат читаете.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); тогда заголовок в выводе не покажет, покажет только тело ответа.

Comment: А что выводит `var_dump($result)`? Добавьте в вопрос

Comment: Проблема в том, что используя curl на один url я отлично получаю ссылку, но стоит только начать обрабатывать массив переменных из адресов(я делал предварительный вывод и все url валидны), используя ту же функцию curl  с той же конфигурацией(делая ее вызов), но на каждый из полученных в массиве адресов, как curl просто отказывается работать, присылая в ответ пустой ответ(вчера присылал http 200, сегодня просто пустоту).
CURLOPT_HEADER убирал - теперь вот пустоту присылает.Хотя если сделать отдельный вызов вне цикла на конкретную ссылку, то отлично ее читает и выдает искомую на странице ссылку.

Comment: UPD - Добавил в вопрос вывод var_dump($result).

Answer (score 0):

Нашел пока что единственное рабочее решение - выгружать каждую ссылку в файл(именно в файл, не в массив) и потом считывать его и делать обход по каждой ссылке отдельным циклом, вне основного, так же заново инициализируя curl библиотеку.Получился нейкий велосипед, но всетаки работает.